# Django Media Directory HTTP 404 for Uploaded Images

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-media, django-uploads

My project structure is:

```
- api/
    - urls.py
    ...
- avatars/
    - 16701016.jpg
    - 16701019.jpg
    ...
- frontend/
    - static/
        - frontend/
    - templates/
    - urls.py
    ...
- website/
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    ...
```

Part of the `settings.py` file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath('../avatars/')
MEDIA_URL = '/avatars/'
```

The contents of `/website/urls.py` :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    re_path(r'^.*', include('frontend.urls'))
]
```

Now I need to access the `/avatars/*.jpg` files via URL like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/avatars/*.jpg`

But It is not working (Just 404). What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the MEDIA_ROOT value from:

   ```
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath('../avatars/')
   ```

   to:

   ```
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.abspath('avatars')
   ```
2. And also append the following code in `urls.py`:

   ```
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```

Comment: TypeError: static() got an unexpected keyword argument 'document_root'

Comment: django version issue! 
For 2.1 : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I just imported the wrong module. It is working well as expected. Thank you.